# Accept paypal with braintree production account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

With Braintree sandbox account, PayPal is enabled by default. With use of dropin js and sandbox API keys, payment form looks like this for me in sandbox account. 
[image: braintree sandbox]

I am using following code as given in braintree documentation,

```
<script>
    braintree.setup(
            // Replace this with a client token from your server
            "{{$clientToken}}",
            'dropin', {
                container: 'dropin'
            });
</script>
```

But when I use **Production API keys**, the **PayPal option is not visible** anymore. I only see credit card form. I have linked PayPal merchant account to Braintree and PayPal seems to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Reposting from a comment as I think this may have gotten to the bottom of it.</sub>

I'm one of the developers that works on the Pay with PayPal product at Braintree. PayPal should be enabled for you in production once you've linked your account. There are a few things that could be going wrong, e.g. if you're using a currency that isn't supported, or using a very old browser and a web page that doesn't use HTTPS.

If you're still having issues getting the PayPal button I encourage you to [drop an email to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) and they will help you see what the issue is.